# Copy List Item to Folder in Seperate List

Tags: list, sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I have two lists, List A and List B. I have folders in List B. Can I set up a workflow that copies list items from List A to a specific folder in List B?

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it does'nt seem the most appropriate.

You could use a custom action available in the ribbon or in the edit control block.
When you select a folder, you click on this custom action and launch a javascript function or a postback. And then, you program your copy.

Custom action :
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/adding-custom-action-to-the-ribbon-of-view-in-sharepoint-list-library/

Code example to move folder:
[Moving a SharePoint folder and contents to different location in same Document Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317887/moving-a-sharepoint-folder-and-contents-to-different-location-in-same-document-l)